# Seahorse giving permissions for a keyring for all applications at once

Tags: gnupg, gnome-keyring, seahorse

After when one of my app asks for a password to open a gnome keyring - some(or all) of my apps(firefox, seahorse ui etc.) gain permission to see everything from that keyring. Is it a bug or it has been designed such way?

Comment: Seahorse is designed to be "one stop shopping", it keeps all your passwords and unlocks them all at once. Probably your best option is to decide what, if any, applications/passwords you want to be managed this way. If you have an application or password that you do NOT want to be managed this way, remove it from seahorse. It is more a work around, but seahorse was not designed to give fine grained control of passwords.

Comment: "If you have an application or password that you do NOT want to be managed this way, remove it from seahorse." - so far, seahorse is useless. Any alternative? Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I do not know any password manager that gives fine grain of control.

Comment: keypassx is in the repos and it is portable (run on a flash drive on other OS)